# How to prevent page faults after child exits?

Tags: linux, memory, fork, copy-on-write

A nice way of creating a snapshot of a process is to use [`fork()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) to create a child process. The memory of the child process will be a copy of the parent process.

Instead of eagerly copying all the memory, the OS simply marks the pages as *copy-on-write*: the pages will be cloned if the event of one of the processes writing to it. This saves both time and space, which is great.

In the event the child process exits, the *copy-on-write* behavior should be deactivated. However, I'm getting page faults for the whole array -- is there any way of optimizing these page faults? e.g. similar to how [`MAP_POPULATE`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages//man2/munmap.2.html) avoids page faults for the initial access to the pages of a mapped region.

---

Below there is a simple benchmark that demonstrates the behavior I'm asking about. I check for page faults via `perf stat -e minor-faults,major-faults ./a.out`.

If no child process is created (`WITH_CHILD` set to `false`) I have very few page faults (around `125` and constant). However, just by creating and reaping the child process, I get page faults in everything (around `131260`, proportional to array size). **As the pages are mapped by a single process, I wouldn't expect *any* page faults to happen! Why do they?**

This is a follow-up of [Kernel copying CoW pages after child process exit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56173845/4288486).

```cpp
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 536870912  // 512MB
#define WITH_CHILD true

using inttype = uint64_t;

constexpr uint64_t NUM_ELEMS() {
  return ARRAY_SIZE / sizeof(inttype);
}

int main() {
  // allocate array
  void *arraybuf = mmap(nullptr, ARRAY_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                        MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_POPULATE, -1, 0);
  assert(arraybuf != nullptr);
  std::array<inttype, NUM_ELEMS()> *array =
    new (arraybuf) std::array<inttype, NUM_ELEMS()>();

#if WITH_CHILD
  // spawn checkpointing process
  int pid = fork();
  assert(pid != -1);

  // child process -- do nothing, just exit
  if (pid == 0) {
    exit(0);
  }

  // wait for child thread to exit
  assert(waitpid(pid, nullptr, 0) == pid);
#endif

  // write to array -- this shouldnt generate page faults, right? :(
  std::fill(array->begin(), array->end(), 0);

  // cleanup
  munmap(array, ARRAY_SIZE);
}
```

Comment: Just so we're clear, a page fault does not imply that the page is copied. Upon a page fault the kernel checks whether it needs to copy the page; if it finds that the program has the only copy (refcount = 1) it will skip the copy. The page fault is just how the kernel triggers the check.

Comment: But ideally there should be an option to tell the kernel "false alarm. stop checking for all pages".